# Google Search Console suddenly reports "no data available" instead of the usual 800 backlinks

Tags: seo, google-search-console, backlinks, search

My client Website has 800+ back links to his website from different domains. Suddenly one morning Google Search Console showed no data available in links to my site and internal links.  I usually check it everyday!

I searched for a solution os the Internet and  it might be a bug in Search Console. How would that happen?  It's my first experience with such an issue.

I know that this data can sometimes decrease slowly, but it happened suddenly.  800 backlinks to no data available.  What might be reason for this? Is this problem related to my SEO submissions which I do regularly?

Comment: It's a google bug and i am also facing the same issue in webmasters. It will be resolved in next 1-2 days.

Comment: No data available should not scare you. It is a default message when a query fails. Keep in mind that when you are using GSC you are using a system completely separate from the search engine and may not always have the data you want. It does not mean the search engine does not have back links for your​ site. This is a common error.

Comment: Thank You @closetnoc for giving Your Time in answering it.